# state not being updated before api call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, express

I'm building a marketplace where a user get to add his own product to it. I have a form component where the user input details about his product. I have a category and subcategory fields.  Once the user chooses a category, the subcategory form gets updated ( by making an api call with the new category) with the list of subcategories related to that category. The problem is the api call is made with the oldest category instead of the the new one.

HERE'S MY CODE

```
// let's say the initial category is man 
  const [category, setCategory] = useState("men");

  const changeSelectedCategory = (category) => {
    // let's say the user get to choose women category from the picker component listed 
       below

    setCategory(category);
    // the new category is women
  };

  useEffect(() => {

    // making the api call
     getSubCategoriesApi.request({ category: category });
    // logging the api fetched data. i'm sending back the selected category by the user
    // the problem is here. it keeps logging 'men', yet the new category is women
      console.log(getSubCategoriesApi.data());
     
     console.log(category);
    // this logs correctly the new category, which is women. the state has been 
      successfully updated, yet in my api call it wasn't. 
  }, [category]);

<Picker
    items={categories}
    changeSelectedCategory={changeSelectedCategory}
    placeholder="Categorie"
/>
```

my express code. note that i'm just sending back the category choosen by the user to see if it did get updated correctly.

```
router.post("/products/getSubCategories", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    res.send(req.body);
    // sends old category, men. Yet the user did choose women and 
       state was updated
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).send(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: I think perhaps getSubCategoriesApi.request({ category: category }); is async and has not actually completed when you call, console.log(getSubCategoriesApi.data());

Comment: If that's your issue, the usual pattern is explained succinctly here, https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-use-async-function-in-react-hook-useeffect-typescript-js-6204a788a435

Comment: What is `getSubCategoriesApi.data()`? Seems the more important thing to check is that `category` is correct when calling `getSubCategoriesApi.request({ category });` a line above. From what I can tell you've confirmed the state is correctly updating and you just have some issue with your `getSubCategoriesApi` code.

Comment: @DrewReese the getSubCategoriesApi.data() is returning the data i get from the api call. like i said everything is fine except the state isn't updated :)

Comment: The state did update, otherwise the `useEffect` hook's callback wouldn't have been triggered. You also console log the `category` state value and say it's correct. What is the `category` value right before making the `getSubCategoriesApi.request({ category })` call? Is it possible you are mutating the `category` state elsewhere? Can you provide us a [complete and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? This doesn't seem to be an issue with React.

Comment: i m going to check this out :)

Comment: @DrewReese isn't related to the fact that the api calls are made asynchronously?

Comment: Is *what* related to API calls being asynchronous? The `useEffect` hook callback is triggered by the `category` state updating... it doesn't really matter what happens afterwards. Yes, network requests are asynchronous.

Comment: @DrewReese i just found another way of making it work. i was using using apisauce for making my api requests. what i did though, for that api call exclusively is use axios in useeffect function. Note that i m import my api config from another file in that example. i instead used axios and somehow made it work ...

Comment: Right on! Like I said, from all that you described it seemed the state was updating and that there was only an issue with the API code you were using. Glad you got it sorted out though. Cheers.

Comment: @DrewReese thansk a lot buddy !, but the fact api sauce didn't update the body seems confusing to me ....

Comment: BTW, if you want to update your question to include the `getSubCategoriesApi` code you were using we may be able to get it straightened out.

Comment: Thanks. Nothing seems odd or out of sorts with the `useApi` hook logic. Odd.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like changeSelectedCategory is being called unless you are calling it inside the Picker Component which can not be seen.

You should use a promise when waiting for data.

```
getSubCategoriesApi.request({ category: category })
.then(response => {
    console.log(getSubCategoriesApi.data());
  }).catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

i Somehow made it work by using axios as api client instead of previously used apisauce.

my api sauce hook

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default useApi = (apiFunc) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const request = async (...args) => {
    setLoading(true);
    const response = await apiFunc(...args);
    setLoading(false);

    if (!response.ok) return setError(true);

    setError(false);
    setData(response.data);
  };

  return { data, error, loading, request };
};
```

My api call

````
import { create } from "apisauce";

const apiClient = create({
  baseURL: "http://192.168.1.42:5000/",
});

const endpoint = "/products";

const getSubCategories = (category) =>
  client.post(`${endpoint}/getSubCategories`, category);

export default {
  getSubCategories,
};
```
Form component ( previous one that didn't work )
```
const getProductsCategoriesApi = useApi(listingsApi.getCategories)
const [category, setCategory] = useState("men");

  const changeSelectedCategory = (category) => {
    // let's say the user get to choose women category from the picker component listed 
       below

    setCategory(category);
    // the new category is women
  };

  const getProductsSubCategoriesApi = useApi(listingsApi.getSubCategories);

  useEffect(() => {

    // making the api call
     getSubCategoriesApi.request({ category: category });
    // logging the api fetched data. i'm sending back the selected category by the user
    // the problem is here. it keeps logging 'men', yet the new category is women
      console.log(getSubCategoriesApi.data());
     
     console.log(category);
    // this logs correctly the new category, which is women. the state has been 
      successfully 
}, [categorySelected]);
````

the new api call that did work using axios and ditching api hook i created

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/products/test", { name: categorySelected })
      .then(function (response) {
        // successfully logs the new category. 
        console.log(response.data);

      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
      })
      .then(function () {
        // always executed
      });
  }, [categorySelected]);
```